# Power series in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

In complex analysis of one variable, we have the series $\sum_nz^n$ is convergent for $|z|<1$. If i consider the same in $\mathbb{C}^2$, that the series $\sum_{n_1,n_2}z_1^{n_1}z_2^{n_2}$, for $|z_i|<1$ $i=1,2.$ Is this series convergent?
Or is this true in general spaces?

Comment: Since that particular power series is the product of two power series in one variable, it is easy to see that the domain of convergence is exactly $\mathbb{D}\times \mathbb{D}$. The general situation is more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
\sum_{n_1=0}^{N_1}\sum_{n_2=0}^{N_2} z_1 ^{n_1}z_2 ^{n_2}
= \sum_{n_1=0}^{N_1}z_1 ^{n_1} \times \sum_{n_2=0}^{N_2} z_2 ^{n_2}
$$

Comment: taking $N_1$ fixed and letting $N_2\to \infty$, we get on the right the term $\frac{1}{1-z_2}$, and on left the expression $\sum_{n_1=0}^{N_1}\sum_{n_2=0}^{\infty}z_1^{n_1}z_2^{n_2}$. Now letting $N_1\to \infty$, we get the desired. Am i correct?

Comment: @user1123 my point being, the LHS is convergent iff both terms of the product of the RHS are.

Comment: can we use the same idea to prove it in case of $\mathbb{C}^3$